# Why do Species 8472 have such formidable weapons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

When we encounter Species 8472 we are told that they are the only species native to fluidic space, that they act pretty much as a unified force and that fluidic space lacks planets.

Since planet-busters would be no use in a region of space with no planets and since they have no obvious enemies to use these weapons on, **why do they have such formidable weaponry in the first place?**

Comment: Even if they've not been able to *access* non-fluidic space, they may have been **aware of it** for a considerable amount of time, in the same way that Starfleet are aware of subspace realms.

Comment: IMO their is stuff in lower cannon/STO which goes into some of this and could potentially give an answer to this question

Comment: @markthompson I tried to put the question back in scope by asking for canon reasoning instead of speculation/any reason at all. Feel free to revert if you feel like I butchered your question :)

Comment: No, i can cope with a bit of judicious editing

Comment: I guess that something that causes less damage in fluidic space might cause more damage in our space and they realised it early on. So it could be that it's almost a coincidence that their tech is so dangerous. We've often seen Starfleet tech have an unexpected effect on other situations in what to me seems a similar style to what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Species 8472 might be the only species *currently* living in fluidic space, but there could well have been other species that they wiped out. Their morphology (arms, legs etc.) suggests a conventional terrestrial origin rather than fluidic space, so they may well not be "native". Another alternative is that the Borg were not the first to invade fluidic space (and/or whereever the species originated from) - they are notably highly xenophobic, perhaps due to previous hostilities with other species. There's nothing canon about this subject that I could find though.

Comment: I keep wishing that there were a really good answer to this really good question, but I haven't been able to come up with one, myself. On the surface, if they really were alone in their universe (which is itself biologically unlikely), they ought to be either docile (having never developed any reason to be aggressive and compete) or extinct (having developed a need to compete against each other and eventually wiped themselves out). The latter possibility is the closest to an answer I can think of -- they developed weapons for competition amongst themselves. But it's pure speculation.

Answer (score 4):

## A tool in one context can become a weapon in another.

A handheld laser pointer can be used as an aid for directing attention during a presentation, or a toy to activate the chase instinct in your favorite domestic carnivore.  But it can also be used to permanently blind an adversary or to start fires.  A more powerful laser can be used for communication over vast distances or as an efficient means of transporting energy.  Such a laser can also be used as a weapon if directed at targets unprepared to receive the beam.

The powerful beam species 8472 used to wreck ships and destroy planets
could be their equivalent of a laser used to send power or communications through the non-vacuum of fluidic space.  Only in our universe would it seem a ridiculously powerful weapon.